# Yeoman / Grunt: adding subdirectories to project

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman

I am building a web with `Yeoman`, and I'm trying to create the following structure:

```
app/index.html -> /
app/support/index.html -> /support
...etc
```

The issue comes when I run *grunt* to build the **dist** directory. The files in **support** subdirectory don't get processed.

**How can this be achieved?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which generator you used but mostly you need to change the `*.html` or `{,*/}*.html` lines in your `Gruntfile.js` to `**/*.html` so it will look in subdirectories as well.